# Macbook Cursor does not show

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My daughter's Macbook Air does not show a Cursor, although ⌘+Tab shows it.
How do I force it to display normally?

Comment: (First time I noticed)... does alt-tab show a hand or another cursor?

Answer (score 1):

Try following troubleshooting steps:

1 - Start in Safe mode (reboot, hold <kbd>shift</kbd> right after the startup chime)

if cursor shows then it is a 3party software

2 - Log in as other user (Guest)

if cursor shows it is your (daughters) user profile that needs fixing

If none of above worked, it is your Trackpad app that needs fixing.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "trackpad app"?

Comment: Literature: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1248, or http://osxdaily.com/2013/07/19/disappearing-mouse-cursor-mac-os-x/....

Comment: I'm not seeing any reference to a "trackpad app" anywhere within either articles. Could you clarify what you are referring to, preferably with a quote? Also, Safe Mode does not rule out 3rd-party app involvement as apps can still be run in Safe Mode.